# Allow freeform extension for document types in NSSavePanel

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I have a document-based application with 3 document types (Type A, Type B, Type C) configured as editor in the info.plist. How can I make it so that Type A will allow the user to set whatever file name they want when saving, without forcing any particular extension, while still being able to choose from the 3 different formats?

What I’ve tried:

1. Setting the NSSavePanel’s `allowsOtherFileTypes` to `true` in my NSDocument’s `prepareSavePanel()` function. This isn’t sufficient because it only works if the user enters an extension that isn’t currently known by the system (e.g. “My document.foo” will still save as “My Document.foo.typea”).
2. Not setting a type identifier on the document type in the info.plist. This actually worked reasonably well up until macOS 13, where it logs an error about a UTI that wasn't exported and won't offer that type in the save panel.
3. Setting a blank extension on the exported type in the info.plist. This almost works but if the user enters a known extension it shows a prompt like this:

> You have used the extension “.txt” at the end of the name. The standard extension is “.”.

4. Not setting any extension on the exported type in the info.plist. This seemed to work great on macOS 13, but on macOS 12 it would show a prompt similar to the above but with “.(null)” rather than “.”.

So, without completely overriding the entire save process, I'm now out of ideas.

Comment: Just an idea: override `runModalSavePanel(for:delegate:didSave:contextInfo:)` and run your own save panel.

Comment: 1. Is the extension visible?

Comment: @Willeke Yeah thanks, I could resort to that if there’s no other option. 
1. Say the default name showing is “Untitled.typea”. The user changes the name to “My Document.foo”, but it still silently appends “.typea”. I’ve set `isExtensionHidden` to false but it still does this.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by allowing the user to type whatever filename extension possible? (Do you want a doc of `typea` to be saved as `typeb` by typing that name, or what?) Otherwise, how are you going to determine the type of document if not by filename extension (i.e. an extended attribute or HFS type code)? FWIW, while they're officially deprecated, you could define the UTIs by specifying only file types '`Gan1`', '`Gan2`', and '`Gan3`', then they'd allow whatever filename extension you wanted.

Comment: @NSGod Imagine a text editor that can save as plain text, but there's a near-infinite number of possible extensions a plain text file might have, including none. They're all valid and aren't necessarily associated with my app but my app can still edit and save them. But then say the app can also save as RTF, which is a distinct format and must have the .rtf extension. Not sure what you mean by `Gan1` etc? Do you mean HFS type codes?

Answer (score 1):

I had another idea which seems to be working on both macOS 12 and 13:

Set the type identifier of the document type to `public.data` in the info.plist.

On macOS 12 this logs a warning about not having a valid extension, but it doesn't show any confusing prompts to the user. I'm still open to other solutions though, if anyone has any.